# Operate different resolvers according to directive result in graphql

Tags: graphql, graphql-js

I'm trying to create a directive in graphql that according to its result, a different resolver will apply. I was looking in graphql documentation and couldn't find a way to do it.
For example, I will have a directive that checks for admin permissions. If the user has admin permission I will resolve the field with one resolver that returns all organization entities. If the user doesn't have admin permissions, I will resolve the field with a different resolver that will return only entities associated with the user's personal account.